# How to add dynamic radio button to dynamic created table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I want to add the radio button to the dynamically created table.
This is the HTML code where I am adding the dynamically created object.

```
<div class="row container">
    <div class=" col m12 l6 s12" style="height:200px; overflow:scroll;">
        <table id="staff">

        </table>
    </div>
    <div class=" col m12 l6 s12" style="height:200px; overflow:scroll;">
        <table id="patient">

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery Code for the website

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/public/src/management/serverfile/selectstaffandpat.php",
     dataType: "text",
     error: function (request, error) {
         console.log(arguments);
         alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
     },
     success: function (JSONObject) {
         var peopleHTML = "";
         var tempjsonval = JSON.parse(JSONObject);
         var str1 = "<tr><th colspan=\"4\">Staff</th></tr><tr><th>Select</th><th>ID</th><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th></tr>";
         var count_staff = tempjsonval.staff.length;
         var count_patient = tempjsonval.patient.length;
         for (i = 0; i < count_staff; i++) {
             str1 += "<tr><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"staff\" value=\"" +
                    tempjsonval.staff[i].s_id +
                    "staff\" ></input></td><td>" +
                    tempjsonval.staff[i].s_id +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    tempjsonval.staff[i].firstname +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    tempjsonval.staff[i].lastname +
                    "</td></tr>"
         }

         document.getElementById("staff").innerHTML = str1;

         str1 = "";
         str1 = " <tr><th colspan=\"3\">Patient</th></tr><tr><th>ID</th><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th></tr>";
         for (i = 0; i < count_patient; i++) {
             str1 += "<tr><td>" +
                    tempjsonval.patient[i].p_id +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    tempjsonval.patient[i].firstname +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    tempjsonval.patient[i].lastname +
                    "</td></tr>"
          }
          document.getElementById("patient").innerHTML = str1;
        }
    });
});
```

There is input created but the radio button is not shown. Can anyone please provide a way to add a radio button with dynamic value.
[this is the image where I am getting this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScmEQ.png)

Comment: Just add line `str1 += "<tr><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"patient\" value=\"" +
                    tempjsonval.patient[i].p_id  +
                    "patient\" ></input></td><td>" +` in count_patient object appending in table

Comment: what i was asking was about adding radio button to the staff.
          str1 += "<tr><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"staff\" value=\"" +
                    tempjsonval.staff[i].s_id +
                    "staff\" ></input></td><td>" +


This is not working

Comment: And radio button select individual related to table rows? one all rows select single row?

Comment: Please check this demo [link](https://jsfiddle.net/szay647q/) you won't like this or something else?

Comment: For this, you  need to prepared dynamic radio name or prepared array variable based on the index you got values specific selected radio.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one needs to changes some JSON data to ajax response data.

For testing check working demo [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/szay647q/)

> HTML content

```
<div class="row container">
            <div class=" col m12 l6 s12" style="height:200px; overflow:scroll;">
                <table id="staff">

                </table>
            </div>
            <div class=" col m12 l6 s12" style="height:200px; overflow:scroll;">
                <table id="patient">

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

> Javascript Code

```
var JSONObject = '{"staff":[{"s_id":1,"firstname":"A","lastname":"B"},{"s_id":1,"firstname":"A","lastname":"B"}],"patient":[{"p_id":1,"firstname":"A","lastname":"B"},{"p_id":1,"firstname":"A","lastname":"B"}]}';
  var peopleHTML = "";
            var tempjsonval = JSON.parse(JSONObject);
            console.log(tempjsonval);
            var str1 = "<tr><th colspan=\"4\">Staff</th></tr><tr><th>Select</th><th>ID</th><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th></tr>";
            var count_staff = tempjsonval.staff.length;
            var count_patient = tempjsonval.patient.length;
            for (i = 0; i < count_staff; i++) {
                str1 += "<tr><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"staff["+i+"]\" value=\"" +
                    tempjsonval.staff[i].s_id +
                    "staff\" ></input></td><td>" +
                    tempjsonval.staff[i].s_id +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    tempjsonval.staff[i].firstname +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    tempjsonval.staff[i].lastname +
                    "</td></tr>"

            }

            document.getElementById("staff").innerHTML = str1;

            str1 = "";
            str1 = " <tr><th colspan=\"3\">Patient</th></tr><tr><th>ID</th><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th></tr>";
            for (i = 0; i < count_patient; i++) {
                str1 += "<tr><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"patient["+i+"]\" value=\"" + tempjsonval.patient[i].p_id + "patient\" ></input></td><td>" +
                    tempjsonval.patient[i].firstname +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    tempjsonval.patient[i].lastname +
                    "</td></tr>"
            }
        document.getElementById("patient").innerHTML = str1;
```

> OutPut

[image]

Note: you need to prepared radio button unique or dynamic either prepared array variable.

Comment: I have added an image to the output that I am getting for the staff. 
Radio button.
Plus I want only one Name for all Radio Button in one complete table with different values.

Comment: If you put the same radio button name you can't select multiple insed of you to need to put the checkbox. if you want a single radio button name and store all selected values you need map in `array object`.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot.
Code is working perfectly.
Issue was with the materialize CSS that i was using.
It was Restricting me create elements of radio.

Comment: Ok, bro enjoyed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/public/src/management/serverfile/selectstaffandpat.php",
dataType: "text",
error: function (request, error) {
    console.log(arguments);
    alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
},
success: function (JSONObject) {
    var peopleHTML = "";
    var tempjsonval = JSON.parse(JSONObject);
    var str1 = `<tr><th colspan="4">Staff</th></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>FirstName</th>
                    <th>LastName</th>
                </tr>`;

    var count_staff = tempjsonval.staff.length;
    var count_patient = tempjsonval.patient.length;
    for (i = 0; i < count_staff; i++) {
        str1 +=`<tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="staff" value="${tempjsonval.staff[i].s_id} staff /></td>
        <td>${tempjsonval.staff[i].s_id}</td><td>
            ${tempjsonval.staff[i].firstname}</td>
            <td>${tempjsonval.staff[i].lastname}</td></tr>`}


    document.getElementById("staff").innerHTML = str1;

    str1 = "";

    str1 = `<tr>
            <th colspan="3">Patient</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            </tr>`;
    for (i = 0; i < count_patient; i++) {
        str1 +=`<tr>
        <td>${tempjsonval.patient[i].p_id}</td>
        <td>${tempjsonval.patient[i].firstname}</td>
        <td>${tempjsonval.patient[i].lastname}</td>
        </tr>`
    }
    document.getElementById("patient").innerHTML = str1;

}
```

});

try to use template literal it's a nice feature